# TypeError: batch_text_or_text_pairs has to be a list (got )

Tags: encoding, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I'm getting this error. I'm running this exact code from https://www.kaggle.com/code/perevalov540/multiclass-text-classification-with-transformers/notebook

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File :1

Cell In[20], line 5, in regular_encode(texts, tokenizer, maxlen)
      1 def regular_encode(texts, tokenizer, maxlen=512):
      2     """
      3     encodes text for a model
      4     """
----> 5     enc_di = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
      6         texts,
      7         return_token_type_ids=False,
      8         padding='max_length',
      9         max_length=None
     10         
     11     )
     13     return np.array(enc_di['input_ids'])

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py:2473, in PreTrainedTokenizerBase.batch_encode_plus(self, batch_text_or_text_pairs, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, stride, is_split_into_words, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs)
   2463 # Backward compatibility for 'truncation_strategy', 'pad_to_max_length'
   2464 padding_strategy, truncation_strategy, max_length, kwargs = self._get_padding_truncation_strategies(
   2465     padding=padding,
   2466     truncation=truncation,
   (...)
   2470     **kwargs,
...
   (...)
    382         pad_to_multiple_of=pad_to_multiple_of,
    383     )

TypeError: batch_text_or_text_pairs has to be a list (got )
```

This is the function that's giving error.

```
def regular_encode(texts, tokenizer, maxlen=512):
    """
    encodes text for a model
    """
    enc_di = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
        texts,
        return_token_type_ids=False,
        padding='max_length',
        max_length=None
    )

    return np.array(enc_di['input_ids'])
```

Comment: The error message means that your `texts` is not a list of strings. Try to print `texts` to see what is going on.